# Xamarin HttpClient crash on first boot on Android

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin

Hello everyone I'm writing a cross platform app that need to get some data from a url endpoint, here is the method:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Ottiene tutte le informazioni visualizzabili nell'applicazione
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task ottieniInformazioniAsync() {

            if (contentDownloaded)
                return;


            Action action = () => { ottieniInformazioniAsync(); };

            this.wrapper = await PersistanceStorage.PersistanceStorage.Instance.getInformations();

            if (wrapper == null)
                await App.showAwaitableMessage("Si è verificato un errore nell'ottenimento delle informazioni.", "Errore", "Riprova", action);
            else
                contentDownloaded = true;

            this.wrapper.generaOggetto(this);

        }
```

The app start crashing where I'm calling the  *PersistanceStorage.PersistanceStorage.Instance.getInformations();*method, here is the body:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Ottiene tutte le informazioni dalla base di dati
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<InformationContainer.InformationWrapper> getInformations() {

            var url = URLREST + "/getInformazioni";
            var request = await requestData(url);
            if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InformationCallWrapper>(content);

                    return wrapper.data;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Errore download informazioni" + e);

                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

only when I'm running the app on android, and only in the first run of the app everything crash calling the  *await requestData(url); method:*

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Effettua una richiesta http ad una risorsa
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The data.</returns>
    /// <param name="url">URL.</param>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> requestData(String url)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
        try
        {
            return await RestClient.GetAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
    [Mono] Loading reference 2 of System.Net.Http.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0x74a6364880] -> System.Core[0x74ade3bb00]: 11
[capitale.ctsap] 0xebadde09 skipped times: 0
[mono-rt] /proc/self/maps:
[mono-rt] 12c00000-12f80000 rw-p 00000000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 12f80000-13080000 ---p 00380000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 13080000-13180000 rw-p 00480000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 13180000-134c0000 rw-p 00580000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 134c0000-13540000 ---p 008c0000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 13540000-13580000 rw-p 00940000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 13580000-13940000 ---p 00980000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 13940000-13980000 rw-p 00d40000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 13980000-14080000 ---p 00d80000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 14080000-140c0000 rw-p 01480000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 140c0000-14100000 ---p 014c0000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 14100000-2ac00000 rw-p 01500000 00:01 19984                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_3233_3233 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 6f28d000-6f567000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 79                                 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.art
[mono-rt] 6f567000-6f57d000 r--p 002da000 fe:01 79                                 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.art
[mono-rt] 6f57d000-6f6b2000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 89                                 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-libart.art
[mono-rt] 6f6b2000-6f6c4000 r--p 00135000 fe:01 89                                 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-libart.art
[mono-rt] 6f6c4000-6f704000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 98                                 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-conscrypt.art
[mono-rt] 6f704000-6f707000 r--p 00040000 fe:01 98                                 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-conscrypt.art
[mono-rt] 6f707000-6f74e000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 103                                /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-okhttp.art
[mono-rt] 6f74e000-6f752000 r--p 00047000 fe:01 103                                /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-okhttp.art
[mono-rt] 6f752000-6f7b8000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 114                                /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-bouncycastle.art
[mono-rt] 6f7b8000-6f7bf000 r--p 00066000 fe:01 114                                /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-bouncycastle.art
[mono-rt] 6f7bf000-6f820000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 117                                /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-apache-xml.art
[mono-rt] 6f820000-6f827000 r--p 00061000 fe:01 117                                /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-apache-xml.art
[mono-rt] 6f827000-6f86b000 rw-p 00000000 fe:01 121                            

    /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ext.art
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7fe3f58cf0 in tid 24999 (capitale.ctsapp), pid 24999 (capitale.ctsapp)
```

I don't get why the crash happen only on the first boot and only on Android platform, maybe is some permission or nugget missing?

Comment: How about wrapping it in a try catch and seeing what the actual error is? or logging the actual error, as it stands that stack trace shows no information at all

Comment: Finally got the error, I'm going to investigate more...

Comment: You can post the detail of this error,so that others could help you better.